# Receiving Money on Electrum

Tags: wallet, electrum, cryptofinance

I just started using Electrum noticing there are quite a few Public-Private key combinations(addresses) in the wallet. Every time I do a 'receive' transaction, Electrum uses a new Public key. This has resulted in my funds being spread across multiple addresses (each of these pairs is a wallet, as per my understanding).

Similar Issue: [No sign of my private keys in Electrum wallet ... where do I find them?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11433/no-sign-of-my-private-keys-in-electrum-wallet-where-do-i-find-them)

Download Link: https://electrum.org/ (Not Malicious)

I'm very confused how would I send my funds now. This is not something I would like the wallet program to do for me. I guess it creates this new recieve address for privacy but now how does one get funds out to spend?

I am new to crypto. Can someone please explain me.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original answer was written when my impression was that you were asking why Bitcoin wallets use new addresses on each new payment process. At this point, you have described so many strange behaviors that my impression is that you are running malware instead of Electrum. Some red flags are:

- Wallets do not move funds without a user interaction.
- Your wallet informs you that the output address is "Not known, this is a non-wallet txid".

I would suggest that you attempt moving your funds to a new wallet controlled by a different device. If you succeed, you’re good and I’m misunderstanding the situation, but it seems to me that your funds have been stolen.

Comment: I’m not able to understand how to use electrum to send funds when this kind of situation happens. Can you please guide me?

Comment: This kind of situation is the normal situation. Just click the "Send" tab at the top of the screen - it will ask for the receiver's address and amount to be sent.

Comment: How can you send given the address electrum sent to is not the original address I got funds on

Comment: @caliGeek: I’m having a hard time telling whether you are a) talking about [change outputs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/736/5406), b) the wallet creating fresh receive addresses after each transaction, or c) your funds were immediately swept from your wallet right after you received them. Could you perhaps elaborate your description or show us a screenshot (feel free to cover private information such as exact amounts, anything past the first ~7 characters of an address, txids, etc.).

Comment: https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/transactions/btc/596802d0b3f99149b6c7b4250ce52894938d252aa3ad4fdbf125336bb0c80553

I got the deposits and then a new UTXO gets created at a new address. Not happy with electrum behavior here

Comment: Which of these addresses are yours? Just the two on the left or all three?

Comment: If you didn't send 3.73118785 BTC to 
bc1qa4hrzegkrrq5fmyelma2y3lcs2papk5ee7suns
 it means someone else probably has - maybe they got access to your keys, they tricked you into using fake software or some other trickery or security breach.

Comment: Looks like a new output was created out of two inputs which is expected I guess since the second address is listed as a receiving address in electrum. It does this for any small amount deposited which is really strange. I’ve had those coins for a while in ledger live with no issues.

Comment: I’m using a coldcard so to spend I need to sign from coldcard which has not happened and these were new deposits on a new wallet with strong seed

Comment: @Murch I'm referring to b I think based on my issue but posting screenshots

Comment: Wallets don’t just do that for you. Did you send all your funds to yourself? Because, if you didn’t send the 3.73118785 ₿, someone else did. Have you verified that `bc1qa4hrzegkrrq5fmyelma2y3lcs2papk5ee7suns` is your address?

Comment: Looks like electrum or the program did immediately after making the deposits or the miner . Sharing some screenshots from Specter. If you look at my screenshots , it contains a data for scripts taken from Sparrow. The receive addresses were signed to recieve but whats the OP 0 for address ending with suns? The address in the 2 inputs were the 2 recieved addresses I got the coins on

Comment: Another example transaction: f9ad7ce7df96a2af17260ee13b34e498a913297c77e097beb62e80f5ef8b1575

Comment: Using a COLDCARD BRAND NEW - MK4 following all instructions of dice rolls and seeds

Comment: I sent all funds from my own ledger live wallet to my cold card wallet [BRAND NEW]. It was a self transfer

Comment: You haven’t answered whether it is your address. Do you still control the funds?

Comment: Electrum states it’s a second receiving address so I’m just confused how to send now since the consolidated funds sit over there now. The UI is not very clear on how to send when this happens

Comment: @Murch I have the private keys for the two inputs linked to the output

Comment: Yeah, but that money has been spent already. Did you see that I edited my answer? It is likely that your money was stolen.

Comment: https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/8686#issuecomment-1809471904